# Calculate total with checkbox and select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Does anyone know the best method to calculate the total of checkbox / select values in a package style format?

For example:

I select website at £50, the total is £50
I select a logo at £15, the total is now £65
I select 2 from licences (£5 each) from a drop down, the total is now £75

I have this fiddle so far: https://jsfiddle.net/ctvgqq0h/ which has the checkbox functionality I'm after, but I'm failing at the select option hurdle.

```
$('select#office').change(function() {
    var number = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    //alert(number);
    add += number;
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've had a look through various resources.

Comment: Here is what I understood, you want to add the number selected from the dropdown? which is currently not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your very close with what you've already got there's just a couple things you need to do.

Firstly, as your checking the value of the drop down inside the check function at the same time as everything else you don't need to wrap it in a `change` event itself, just call it via the elements `onchange` attribute like you did for the checkboxes.

Secondly you don't need the `$(this).find()` as its in the wrong scope you can get away with `$('option:selected')`

Thirdly(!), the value you get back from the drop down will be a string which will need parsing to an int, this can catch you out in javascript as it will often try to parse a number as base 8 rather than base 10.

Then you just need to multiply the value from the drop down list by your cost before adding.

All together it looks a little like this.

```
    var number = $('option:selected').text();
    add += parseInt(number,10) * 5.00
```

I would also suggest adding a 0 value to the top of your drop down list just to avoid any peculiar behaviour.

[Heres an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uysfsnf3/)

Comment: Ah I see! I had no idea about the int number issue either! Thank you Simon

Comment: [More about the parseInt issue can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) it only really happens if you have a leading 0 on your string, and newer implementations shouldn't do this any more however it's caught enough developers out over the years that it's just good practice to declare your radix.